# Unable to add action bar in android in the tablet view

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to display the action bar (along with optionsMenu) for the tablet view as well. However it is not coming for the tablet but it is coming for the phone. On adding the android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar(commented out below) in the tablet layout, it showed a blank screen with the action bar.

Layout for tablet
layout-sw600dp/activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
    tools:context="akshit.android.com.popularmovies.MainActivity">

    <!--
    This layout is a two-pane layout for the Items master/detail flow.

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >
-->

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_movie_main"
        android:name="akshit.android.com.popularmovies.MainActivityFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/movie_detail_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4" />

   <!-- </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar> -->

</LinearLayout>
```

base layout of activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="akshit.android.com.popularmovies.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can chnage it in res/values/styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

with changing NoActionBar to ActionBar like:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
```

Comment: Bad idea to use ActionBar theme due to the fact that author has Toolbar in layout

Answer (score 0):

The issue is pretty simple. You're using `LinearLayout` with `"horizontal"` orientation. This means that you `Toolbar` with `android:layout_width="match_parent"` will take all available space, so your fragments placed out of the screen. You could use something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:baselineAligned="false"
              android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
              tools:context="akshit.android.com.popularmovies.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_movie_main"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/movie_detail_container"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Result:
[image: Landscape orientation]